# Webview called by Preference Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-fragmentactivity, preferencefragment

I've recently created a settings view in my android app by using PreferenceFragment and PreferenceActivity.  I'm listening for preference clicks in my PreferenceFragment.  Initially I had a screen:

```
<Preference
    android:title="webpage">
    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="www.google.com"/>
</Preference>
```

...using that XML, but what I realized was I can't manipulate cookies with an intent that just opens an external page.  I needed a webview but I'm uncertain how I can create a webview in my Fragment.  It kind of looks like this right now:

```
public class test extends PreferenceFragment{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    findPreference("menu_item1").setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            //create webview here
            return true;
        }
    });
```

How should I go about filling up my findPreference and set it to fire the webview from there to point to, let's say, google.com?